# When trying to import GeoTiff source in openlayers get error TS2304 AbstractDecoder

Tags: angular, openlayers, angular12, openlayers-6

When I try to compile my web application using Angular 12 and Open layers if I try to compile the code with the line

```
import GeoTIFF from 'ol/source/GeoTIFF';
```

I get 2 errors.

```
Error: node_modules/geotiff/dist-node/geotiffimage.d.ts:67:118 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Source'.
```

This error I resolved by adding an import to ol/source/Source.

the last error I get which I cant find anywhere else online when I search for it is

```
Error: node_modules/geotiff/dist-node/geotiffimage.d.ts:136:100 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AbstractDecoder'.
```

which I cant find any way to import or any documentation on.

I installed OL with the by npm install ol and npm install @types/ol and its a fresh project from there so I have no idea why I'm getting this error or how to resolve it.

Any advice to resolve this or links to resources would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the v6.6.0 of OpenLayers, the TS declarations are included in the ol packages, so you don't need to install @types/ol anymore (see the release notes [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.6.0)). Removing the package should solve your problem.

I recommand you as well to set `"skipLibCheck": true` in the `"compilerOptions"` of your `tsconfig.json`, as suggested [in this Git issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/12497#issuecomment-878075795) to avoid further problems with types definitions. Here is an example :

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: I never had @types/ol installed but did have this same problem.  It was solved by adding the skipLibCheck flag to tsconfig.